# No sleep or hibernate options on my Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I've been looking around and couldn't find the right answer to fix my problem.

I build my computer today from scratch, but for some reason the Sleep & Hibernate options are disabled and won't let me click them. The Sleep and Hibernate buttons are the ones in the Start menu, when I click on the > arrow next to Shut Down.. Could someone please shed some light on this issue?

Comment: open up a command prompt, and type in `powercfg -a`. Paste the output here. What is the motherboard model?

Answer (score 0):

To enable hibernate open up a elevated command prompt window (run as administrator). Then type

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate on
```

For sleep go into your power plans, click change plan settings and then change advanced settings and see if there is a sleep option there. If not then sleep may not be available. See here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions#